Brouwer fixed point theorem and degree theory
I have heard that a proof of the Brouwer fixed point theorem can be given using the degree of a continuous map. I would like to know if the one I have in mind is correct please.

Let $f:B^n\to B^n$ be a continuous map with $B^n$ the closed unit ball. Then $f$ has a fixed point.

The definition of the degree I used is the following :

The degree of a continuous map $f$ is $\text{deg}(f;y) = \text{deg}(g;y)$ where $y$ is a regular value of $f$ and $\text{deg}(g;y)=\sum_{x\in g^{-1}(y)}\text{sign}\:dg_{x}$ for $g$ a smooth map homotopic to $f$.

Attempt : Suppose it is not the case and that $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in B^n$. We define the map $g :B^n\to B^n$ given by $g(x)=\frac{x-f(x)}{\lVert x-f(x)\rVert}$, it is a continuous and non surjective map since $0$ has empty pre-image, hence its degree is $0$. We define $H(t,x)=(1-t)x + tg(x)$,  we have
$$
\lVert H(t,x)\rVert\leq (1-t)\lVert x\rVert + t\leq 1
$$
And it is an homotopy between the identity map (that has degree $1$) and a non surjective map, this is impossible by the invariance by homotopy of the degree.
Is this proof valid ?
Thank you a lot !

I take for granted the fact that a continuous and non surjective map has degree $0$.

The output of $g$ is not necessarily on $B^n$. You can make it so, by dividing by its length. The assumption that $f$ has no fixed points is used in that division being valid and continuous.

@ameg You are right ! Thank you !

The non-subjectivity of $g$ is, at best, not clear. $H$ can also not be in $B^n$. Its values would also require being normalized.

There are typos and far too many missing steps. What is your definition of degree and on what sort of topological space?

Thank you to both of your for the comments ! I updated the post trying to make clear each step, let me know if it is still unclear and/or false please

Your definition assumes that you have a compact manifold without boundary. A ball does not qualify. (You also have to be careful to argue that you can perturb your continuous map to smooth it and still have the correct codomain.)

@TedShifrin You are right.. How should I proceed please ?

@TedShifrin For your parenthesis I think that I see how to do it with Weierstrass theorem and a « rescaling »

Yes to your last comment. But I would proceed by proving that a fixed-point free map would give a retraction of the ball to its boundary, and then use degree to show that’s impossible.

There are two notions of degree: one is for compact manifolds without boundary (the one you are using) and the other for manifolds with boundary (the one you should be using).

@TedShifrin Thank you I will follow this hint !

@MoisheKohan Thank you for this comment, I have never seen the degree theory for manifolds with boundary in fact… have you a reference please ? To satisfy my curiosity

See the discussion of degree for maps of "regions" here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping#:~:text=The%20degree%20of%20a%20map,role%20in%20topology%20and%20geometry.

@MoisheKohan Thank you !
